# Delegate Used in iOS calendar application being set to null

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode, delegates

I recently downloaded code for creating a calendar in xCode using objective-c. The code works for the most part, it highlights the days a user selects, but it is supposed to log out the start and end dates the user has selected. A delegate is used for this between my view controller and uiview (calendar view), but when my delegate is set in viewDidLoad, I noticed that it is always set to null. I am new to app making so would appreciate any help.

viewcontroller.m:

```
#import "CalendarViewController.h"
#import "DSLCalendarView.h"

@interface CalendarViewController ()<DSLCalendarViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet DSLCalendarView *calendarView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *selectDatesButton;

@end

@implementation CalendarViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad;
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    self.calendarView.delegate = self;
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/
#pragma mark - DSLCalendarViewDelegate methods

- (void)calendarView:(DSLCalendarView *)calendarView didSelectRange:(DSLCalendarRange *)range;
{
    if (range != nil) {
        NSLog( @"Selected %ld/%ld - %ld/%ld", (long)range.startDay.day, (long)range.startDay.month, (long)range.endDay.day, (long)range.endDay.month);
    }
    else {
        NSLog( @"No selection" );
    }
}
```

calendarView.m (not all code, just methods using the delegate)

```
#import "DSLCalendarDayCalloutView.h"
#import "DSLCalendarDayView.h"
#import "DSLCalendarMonthSelectorView.h"
#import "DSLCalendarMonthView.h"
#import "DSLCalendarView.h"
#import "DSLCalendarDayView.h"


@interface DSLCalendarView ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) DSLCalendarDayCalloutView *dayCalloutView;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDateComponents *draggingFixedDay;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDateComponents *draggingStartDay;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL draggedOffStartDay;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableDictionary *monthViews;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *monthContainerView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *monthContainerViewContentView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) DSLCalendarMonthSelectorView *monthSelectorView;

@end


@implementation DSLCalendarView {
    CGFloat _dayViewHeight;
    NSDateComponents *_visibleMonth;
}


- (void)positionViewsForMonth:(NSDateComponents*)month fromMonth:(NSDateComponents*)fromMonth animated:(BOOL)animated;
{
    fromMonth = [fromMonth copy];
    month = [month copy];

    CGFloat nextVerticalPosition = 0;
    CGFloat startingVerticalPostion = 0;
    CGFloat restingVerticalPosition = 0;
    CGFloat restingHeight = 0;

    NSComparisonResult monthComparisonResult = [month.date compare:fromMonth.date];
    NSTimeInterval animationDuration = (monthComparisonResult == NSOrderedSame || !animated) ? 0.0 : 0.5;

    NSMutableArray *activeMonthViews = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    // Create and position the month views for the target month and those around it
    for (NSInteger monthOffset = -2; monthOffset <= 2; monthOffset += 1)
    {
        NSDateComponents *offsetMonth = [month copy];
        offsetMonth.month = offsetMonth.month + monthOffset;
        offsetMonth = [offsetMonth.calendar components:NSCalendarUnitYear | NSCalendarUnitMonth | NSCalendarUnitDay | NSCalendarUnitWeekday | NSCalendarUnitCalendar fromDate:offsetMonth.date];

        // Check if this month should overlap the previous month
        if (![self monthStartsOnFirstDayOfWeek:offsetMonth]) {
            nextVerticalPosition -= _dayViewHeight;
        }

        // Create and position the month view
        DSLCalendarMonthView *monthView = [self cachedOrCreatedMonthViewForMonth:offsetMonth];
        [activeMonthViews addObject:monthView];
        [monthView.superview bringSubviewToFront:monthView];

        CGRect frame = monthView.frame;
        frame.origin.y = nextVerticalPosition;
        nextVerticalPosition += frame.size.height;
        monthView.frame = frame;

        // Check if this view is where we should animate to or from
        if (monthOffset == 0) {
            // This is the target month so we can use it to determine where to scroll to
            restingVerticalPosition = monthView.frame.origin.y;
            restingHeight += monthView.bounds.size.height;
        }
        else if (monthOffset == 1 && monthComparisonResult == NSOrderedAscending) {
            // This is the month we're scrolling back from
            startingVerticalPostion = monthView.frame.origin.y;

            if ([self monthStartsOnFirstDayOfWeek:offsetMonth]) {
                startingVerticalPostion -= _dayViewHeight;
            }
        }
        else if (monthOffset == -1 && monthComparisonResult == NSOrderedDescending) {
            // This is the month we're scrolling forward from
            startingVerticalPostion = monthView.frame.origin.y;

            if ([self monthStartsOnFirstDayOfWeek:offsetMonth]) {
                startingVerticalPostion -= _dayViewHeight;
            }
        }

        // Check if the active or following month start on the first day of the week
        if (monthOffset == 0 && [self monthStartsOnFirstDayOfWeek:offsetMonth]) {
            // If the active month starts on a monday, add a day view height to the resting height and move the resting position up so the user can drag into that previous month
            restingVerticalPosition -= _dayViewHeight;
            restingHeight += _dayViewHeight;
        }
        else if (monthOffset == 1 && [self monthStartsOnFirstDayOfWeek:offsetMonth]) {
            // If the month after the target month starts on a monday, add a day view height to the resting height so the user can drag into that month
            restingHeight += _dayViewHeight;
        }
    }

    // Size the month container to fit all the month views
    CGRect frame = self.monthContainerViewContentView.frame;
    frame.size.height = CGRectGetMaxY([[activeMonthViews lastObject] frame]);
    self.monthContainerViewContentView.frame = frame;

    // Remove any old month views we don't need anymore
    NSArray *monthViewKeyes = self.monthViews.allKeys;
    for (NSString *key in monthViewKeyes) {
        UIView *monthView = [self.monthViews objectForKey:key];
        if (![activeMonthViews containsObject:monthView]) {
            [monthView removeFromSuperview];
            [self.monthViews removeObjectForKey:key];
        }
    }

    // Position the content view to show where we're animating from
    if (monthComparisonResult != NSOrderedSame) {
        CGRect frame = self.monthContainerViewContentView.frame;
        frame.origin.y = -startingVerticalPostion;
        self.monthContainerViewContentView.frame = frame;
    }

    self.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:animationDuration delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut animations:^{
        for (NSInteger index = 0; index < activeMonthViews.count; index++) {
            DSLCalendarMonthView *monthView = [activeMonthViews objectAtIndex:index];
             for (DSLCalendarDayView *dayView in monthView.dayViews) {
                 // Use a transition so it fades between states nicely
                 [UIView transitionWithView:dayView duration:animationDuration options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCrossDissolve animations:^{
                     dayView.inCurrentMonth = (index == 2);
                 } completion:NULL];
             }
        }

        // Animate the content view to show the target month
        CGRect frame = self.monthContainerViewContentView.frame;
        frame.origin.y = -restingVerticalPosition;
        self.monthContainerViewContentView.frame = frame;

        // Resize the container view to show the height of the target month
        frame = self.monthContainerView.frame;
        frame.size.height = restingHeight;
        self.monthContainerView.frame = frame;

        // Resize the our frame to show the height of the target month
        frame = self.frame;
        frame.size.height = CGRectGetMaxY(self.monthContainerView.frame);
        self.frame = frame;

        // Tell the delegate method that we're about to animate to a new month
        if (monthComparisonResult != NSOrderedSame && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(calendarView:willChangeToVisibleMonth:duration:)]) {
            [self.delegate calendarView:self willChangeToVisibleMonth:[month copy] duration:animationDuration];
        }
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        self.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

        if (finished) {
            // Tell the delegate method that we've animated to a new month
            if (monthComparisonResult != NSOrderedSame && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(calendarView:didChangeToVisibleMonth:)]) {
                [self.delegate calendarView:self didChangeToVisibleMonth:[month copy]];
            }
        }
    }];
}
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
{
    DSLCalendarDayView *touchedView = [self dayViewForTouches:touches];
    if (touchedView == nil) {
        self.draggingStartDay = nil;
        return;
    }

    self.draggingStartDay = touchedView.day;
    self.draggingFixedDay = touchedView.day;
    self.draggedOffStartDay = NO;

    DSLCalendarRange *newRange = self.selectedRange;
    if (self.selectedRange == nil) {
        newRange = [[DSLCalendarRange alloc] initWithStartDay:touchedView.day endDay:touchedView.day];
    }
    else if (![self.selectedRange.startDay isEqual:touchedView.day] && ![self.selectedRange.endDay isEqual:touchedView.day]) {
        newRange = [[DSLCalendarRange alloc] initWithStartDay:touchedView.day endDay:touchedView.day];
    }
    else if ([self.selectedRange.startDay isEqual:touchedView.day]) {
        self.draggingFixedDay = self.selectedRange.endDay;
    }
    else {
        self.draggingFixedDay = self.selectedRange.startDay;
    }

    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(calendarView:didDragToDay:selectingRange:)]) {
        newRange = [self.delegate calendarView:self didDragToDay:touchedView.day selectingRange:newRange];
    }
    self.selectedRange = newRange;

    [self positionCalloutViewForDayView:touchedView];

}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
{
    if (self.draggingStartDay == nil) {
        return;
    }

    DSLCalendarDayView *touchedView = [self dayViewForTouches:touches];
    if (touchedView == nil) {
        self.draggingStartDay = nil;
        return;
    }

    DSLCalendarRange *newRange;
    if ([touchedView.day.date compare:self.draggingFixedDay.date] == NSOrderedAscending) {
        newRange = [[DSLCalendarRange alloc] initWithStartDay:touchedView.day endDay:self.draggingFixedDay];
    }
    else {
        newRange = [[DSLCalendarRange alloc] initWithStartDay:self.draggingFixedDay endDay:touchedView.day];
    }

    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(calendarView:didDragToDay:selectingRange:)]) {
        newRange = [self.delegate calendarView:self didDragToDay:touchedView.day selectingRange:newRange];
    }
    self.selectedRange = newRange;

    if (!self.draggedOffStartDay) {
        if (![self.draggingStartDay isEqual:touchedView.day]) {
            self.draggedOffStartDay = YES;
        }
    }

    [self positionCalloutViewForDayView:touchedView];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event;
{
    if (self.draggingStartDay == nil)
    {
        return;
    }

    DSLCalendarDayView *touchedView = [self dayViewForTouches:touches];
    if (touchedView == nil) {
        self.draggingStartDay = nil;
        return;
    }

    if (!self.draggedOffStartDay && [self.draggingStartDay isEqual:touchedView.day]) {
        self.selectedRange = [[DSLCalendarRange alloc] initWithStartDay:touchedView.day endDay:touchedView.day];
    }

    self.draggingStartDay = nil;

    // Check if the user has dragged to a day in an adjacent month
    if (touchedView.day.year != _visibleMonth.year || touchedView.day.month != _visibleMonth.month)
    {
        // Ask the delegate if it's OK to animate to the adjacent month
        BOOL animateToAdjacentMonth = YES;
        if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(calendarView:shouldAnimateDragToMonth:)])
        {
            animateToAdjacentMonth = [self.delegate calendarView:self shouldAnimateDragToMonth:[touchedView.dayAsDate dslCalendarView_monthWithCalendar:_visibleMonth.calendar]];
        }

        if (animateToAdjacentMonth)
        {
            if ([touchedView.dayAsDate compare:_visibleMonth.date] == NSOrderedAscending)
            {
                [self didTapMonthBack:nil];
            }
            else
            {
                [self didTapMonthForward:nil];
            }
        }
    }

    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(calendarView:didSelectRange:)])
    {
        [self.delegate calendarView:self didSelectRange:self.selectedRange];
    }


}
```

calendarView.h

```
#import "DSLCalendarRange.h"
#import "NSDate+DSLCalendarView.h"
@protocol DSLCalendarViewDelegate;


@interface DSLCalendarView : UIView

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<DSLCalendarViewDelegate>delegate;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSDateComponents *visibleMonth;
@property (nonatomic, strong) DSLCalendarRange *selectedRange;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL showDayCalloutView;
@property (nonatomic, assign) BOOL daysSelected;

+ (Class)monthSelectorViewClass;
+ (Class)monthViewClass;
+ (Class)dayViewClass;

- (void)setVisibleMonth:(NSDateComponents *)visibleMonth animated:(BOOL)animated;
- (void)commonInit;

@end


@protocol DSLCalendarViewDelegate <NSObject>

@optional
- (void)calendarView:(DSLCalendarView*)calendarView didSelectRange:(DSLCalendarRange*)range;
- (void)calendarView:(DSLCalendarView *)calendarView willChangeToVisibleMonth:(NSDateComponents*)month duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration;
- (void)calendarView:(DSLCalendarView *)calendarView didChangeToVisibleMonth:(NSDateComponents*)month;
- (DSLCalendarRange*)calendarView:(DSLCalendarView*)calendarView didDragToDay:(NSDateComponents*)day selectingRange:(DSLCalendarRange*)range;
- (BOOL)calendarView:(DSLCalendarView *)calendarView shouldAnimateDragToMonth:(NSDateComponents*)month;
```

Comment: Is it `nil` after this line : `self.calendarView.delegate = self;` ? If yes, it's awkward. How do you check that it's nil ?

Comment: I put in breakpoints and went through that line step by step. The value of the delegate doesn't seem to be set to anything for some reason. In the sample code I downloaded the calendar view at that point was initialised but when I transferred the code to a new project the calendar view has no values set yet

Comment: Did you check that `self.calendarView` is actually not `nil` ?

Comment: I checked and self.calendarView is nil at this point, but when I run the sample app that I downloaded originally, self.calendarView isn't nil at this point, even though I'm using the same code as it, I just transferred the classes to a different project. There must just be a small problem somewhere but I can't figure out what it is

Comment: Since `self.calendarView` is an Outlet it should be loaded with your xib/storyboard. It seems that a connection between interface builder and your class has been lost during your transfer ;)

Comment: I was thinking it had to have been something to do with connecting it to my storyboard but I assumed I already connected it at the start, but because I copied and pasted the code in I realised that I forgot...thanks a million!